# Why is pnpm using a different version to the one in package.json

Tags: pnpm, turborepo

My `package.json` contains this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "typescript": "~4.6.2",
    "jest": "~27.5.1",
    "ts-jest": "~27.1.3",
    "@types/jest": "~27.4.1",
    "@types/uuid": "~8.3.0"
  },
```

I get an error like this when I run `pnpm run test`:

```
 FAIL  test/types/combineModelsByPropertyNameAndType.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a `process` function.

      at ScriptTransformer._getTransformer (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@26.6.2/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:360:13)
      at ScriptTransformer.transformSource (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@26.6.2/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:427:28)
      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@26.6.2/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:569:40)
      at ScriptTransformer.transform (../../node_modules/.pnpm/@jest+transform@26.6.2/node_modules/@jest/transform/build/ScriptTransformer.js:607:25)
```

So despite stating in `devDependencies` that `jest` 27 should be used, its using version 26 in actuality - which is the cause of that error from jest.

For context: I am using `turborepo` as my monorepo management tool, and other modules in my monorepo do use jest 26.  So I am not sure if this is a pnpm question or a turborepo question

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it might be [this issue](https://github.com/pnpm/pnpm/issues/5176). If that is the case, a workaround currently is to set the `hoist=false` in the root `.npmrc`, remove node_modules and reinstall.